# Date countdown on mysql database using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

I would like to create a date countdown column in MySQL using vb.net base on real time date. Even when the system is close it must be still on countdown

For example I have two fields in table (date_added and due_date) I will input 9/20/2015 in my vb.net Form and it will be stored in date_added field in mysql and at the same time it will automatically add a date to due_date field, that is 3 months advance to the date that I input (Example: the date that I input is 9/20/2015 which is added to date_added field and 12/20/2015 will be automatically added to due_date field in mysql) And when the 12/20/2015 comes the program will have a notification when it opens

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following query to check due_date comes .

```
select 1 from table_name where date(now())>=due_date
```

Every time you open your application fire this query to MySQL DB, If returns 1 then show the notification.